# Best app for avatar / profile images on Django

Tags: python, django, django-apps, django-models

In my application I have a model called Product.
Every time a user adds new product should be upload a profile image for that product.

On the web there's a lot of django app for managing images/avatars.

Relying on your experience, which one is the best?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found [django-userena](https://django-userena.org/).

Seems to be very good.

Comment: I feel like userena is way to bloated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the built in model [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield)? You might want to explain why that won't work if you are indeed looking for something else.

Comment: Because I want to resize and thumbnail the profile images, and probably there's an application just for it.

Comment: you might check out [django-imagekit](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit), which is a lighter weight version of [photologue](http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/)

Answer (score 0):

[django-gravatar](https://code.google.com/p/django-gravatar/) is supposed to be good. Can't claim to have used it. The owner is James Tauber and the committers include jezdez, so it's developed by django rockstars.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest django-easy-avatar if you're looking for simple thumbnails and not having to deal with the database or html templates.

[django-easy-avatar on GitHub](https://github.com/chawk/django-easy-avatar)

[django-easy-avatar on Pypi.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi)